# how to download schema-registry maven plugin through gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, groovy

As we know Gradle doesn't have Offcial Kafka Scheam Registry Gradle Plugin . Whenever We try to find out Schema Registry Gradle plugin gradle given suggest to use below plugins.

```
com.github.oasalonen.kafka-schema-registry-gradle-plugin
com.github.imflog.kafka-schema-registry-gradle-plugin
```

Confluent has given maven plugin to work but we need gradle plugin to work.

My question is how to download Scheam Registry Maven plugin through Groovy and use in gradle?

```
kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin
```

Comment: You can't use the maven plugin in Gradle...  This is https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.imflog.kafka-schema-registry-gradle-plugin not good enough?  I've never used it...  What does it miss?

Comment: I am looking for to reuse the maven plugin through groovy and create an plugin and use through task in gradle... i hope it make sense ...

Comment: You can look at the source... https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/tree/master/maven-plugin/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/maven  It all contains references to Maven specific classes...  Are you suggesting to pull maven in as a dependency of your gradle build?

Comment: I don't think you will be successful in what you're trying to do...  And even if you are, I don't think you'll be happy with it...  I would either use the Gradle plugins you mention above, or write your own based on the confluent source....but for Gradle

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you should not attempt to use Maven classes within Gradle.

AFAIK, the `imflog` one is even recommended on Confluent's Slack channels.